# iPhone: Notification Center Trouble

Tags: iphone, xcode, notifications, nsdate

I wrote an app that allows the user to enter data in a UITextField, and one of them allows them to enter in a specific date. I'm trying to have an alert appear in the iPhones Notification Center when the date is 15 hours away, even when the app is not running at all.

EDIT: New code-

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`
`{
    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];`

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMdd"];
NSDate *eventDate=[dateFormatter dateFromString:eventDateField.text];

localNotif.fireDate = [eventDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:-15*60*60];
localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];


localNotif.alertBody = @"Event Tomorrow!";

localNotif.alertAction = @"Show me";

localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotif];
```

`}`

Comment: Sorry for being a little harsh, but you're lacking some very elemental (and crucial) basics. Do yourself a favor and learn them; it won't take long and will save you a lot of time and frustration in the end. A very good book I can recommend is [iOS Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide](http://www.amazon.com/iOS-Programming-Ranch-Guide-Guides/dp/0321773772/). It's written nicely, covers the basics (also *specifically* the stuff you were asking about), and contains nice examples. Do yourself a favor, get it, read it, do the exercises. Won't take long, but will help tremendously.

Comment: Thank you fzwo, yeah I definitely jumped a bit ahead of myself here. I will look into that book today, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the date obtained from the text field in a `NSDate` object, `eventDate`. You will want to set the date with time also. The reason you are getting that error is that `dateByAddingTimeInterval:` should be called on an NSDate object and is not an identifier in itself. Set the `fireDate` of your local notification as

```
localNotif.fireDate=[eventDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:-15*60*60];
```

This will return a date which is 15 hours before the event.

EDIT: You need to create an `NSDateFormatter` object and set its format to how it is stored in `meetingDateField`. Then use the `dateFromString:` to get the `NSDate` from the text field.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"mm'/'dd'/'yyyy"];
NSDate *eventDate=[dateFormatter dateFromString:meetingDateField.text];
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much. But I'm having some issues with the NSDate object grabbing the date from the text field. I set it up like this: `NSDate *eventDate = [NSDate meetingDateField];
    localNotif.fireDate = [eventDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:-480*60];` (The meetingDate is the text field where they type in the date)

Comment: @Joey502 Try the edited answer. Also have a look at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Awesome thank you, but with that new code above I'm getting the error "No known class method for selector "meetingDateField"

Comment: @Joey502 You seem to have a misunderstanding of objects and messages. you can pass messages to meetingDateField. You cannot pass meetingDateField(object) as a message to NSDate class. You should read up on the basics before proceeding further.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah I'm obviously very new to this and learning as I go, I'm sorry for asking dumb questions. I updated my OP with my new code thanks to your help, do you think it looks okay? Thanks again!

Comment: @Joey502 Can you give the input format for the text field? and what is the time of the event on that day?

Comment: Yes, the input format will be "1/18/2011", I decided to do it that way rather than using a date picker for a few different reasons. And I'm not implementing the time, just the specific day, such as a holiday.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! You helped out tremendously! Oh, and just one more thing, just a small warning saying "Control reaches the end of a non-void function", I think I should add a "Return" at the end, not sure what to return though. Thank you so much again!

Comment: @Joey502 You are welcome. You should return a BOOL. just add return YES;

Answer (score 3):

Youre trying to send the message `dateByAddingTimeInterval:` to whom? Nobody. You need a receiver for the message, an object that can then run the method.

```
[[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval: -20*60];
```

(`NSDate date` is the current date and time).

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much. My new code now looks like this: `localNotif.fireDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval: -20*60];` So, will the notification center automatically detect the date that the user enters in that a text field in that view controller, and also when the app is not running? Sorry for the questions, I'm still pretty new.

Comment: No, nobody will detect the date that the user entered. You will have to do that yourself. Check the documentation for `NSDateFormatter`. The method you are looking for is `dateFromString:`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to call `[-dateByAddingTimeInterval:]`, you must have an NSDate object. In your code above, you don't. It should look something like:

```
NSDate* now = [NSDate date];
localNotif.fireDate = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:20*60];
```